# Angularjs: dividing two none-zero scope variables results in NULL

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing a simple pagination and my scope variable disappears after a simple division operation. This must be something so ridiculously silly.

```
.controller('ShowTableCtrl', function($scope, ...) {

  $scope.batch = 15;
  $scope.curpage = 1;

  getTablesS1.count(tid, function (d){
    $scope.rows = d.count;
  });

  $scope.pagenum = ($scope.rows / $scope.batch);

  ...
}
```

So the `$scope.batch` is the number of rows per page to display but it could be any number really.

Now, `$scope.rows` is an integer (number of rows per table) I get via ajax through a service.

So if I test it within a view, both `$scope.rows` and `$scope.batch` are available but 
`$scope.pagenum` is NULL! How is this possible? Why cant I divide `$scope.rows / $scope.batch` if they are both valid none zero integers?

Simple view test
`<span>{{rows}} - {{batch}} - {{curpage}} - {{pagenum}}</span>`

gives me `339 - 15 - 1 - null`

If I don't save the integer in `$scope.rows` and stick the division operation within the service callback, it works for some reason. Like so.

```
getTablesS1.count(tid, function (d){
  $scope.pagenum = d.count / $scope.batch;
});
```

But this is totally not what I want. I want to pull the number of rows once and save it in a scope variable or any variable for that matter, so that I can recalculate the number of pages every time batch changes. And I don't want to do the $http call every time I want to recalculate the page number.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"Now, `$scope.rows` is an integer (number of rows per table) **I get via ajax** through a service."

This is your problem. When the controller is first initialized `$scope.rows` is undefined, since the ajax response hasn't come back yet.

Place a breakpoint on that line and you'll see.

What you see in the view is `339` is probably because the ajax response has come back.

Comment: Thanks. I am probably missing something here. So If both variables are available separately how come the quotient is not available? How do I fix this? If I look at the correct way of doing this I might get this quicker.

Comment: @r.sendecky Please add `console.log($scope.rows)` right before you do the `$scope.pagenum = ...` and notice it's `undefined`. If it is, you must wait for the ajax to return before calculating `$scope.pagenum`.

Comment: You are right. So how do I wait for it? I need to pull the count and save it, then calculate the page number and then display the results. I understand the issue now. But I don't get why it waits for the `$scope.rows` on its own displaying it correct but when it comes to the `$scope.pagenum` it does not wait and displays NULL? I am sorry but this confuses the hell out of me.

Comment: @r.sendecky It is possible that by the time the angular digest process renders its code on the HTML page then the ajax request returned and now `$scope.rows` is now with valid value.

Comment: @r.sendecky So, you should assign `$scope.rows` with the relevant value when the service finishes the request.

Comment: @r.sendecky And only then calculate `$scope.pagenum` of course :)